# Power Resistor in Eagle

Tags: resistors, eaglecad

I'm making a PCB in Eagle. First I found my components, and now I have to put them in Eagle so I can draw the actual board.

Now the problem is, I have found [this](http://be.farnell.com/bourns/pwr263s-35-r500j/resistor-power-0-5r-0-05-35w/dp/2101717) power resistor (I need 0.5 Ohm dissipating at least 4.5W. This one dissipates more, but is apparantly the cheapest I could choose from).

As you can see, there is no CAD design associated with this component. In the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1771760.pdf) there is a *recommended pad layout*, but this would mean that the resistor is layed down on the pcb, whilst al other transistors that might need  a heat sink are placed vertical on the PCB.

So my question is - how must I orient this component (horizontal/vertical/doesn't matter), and how an I find a CAD design to add this to Eagle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TO-263](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-263) is a SMT package and lays flat on the board, with the metal back soldered to a copper pour with optional vias large enough to dissipate the heat generated by the device.

You are unlikely to find this exact component in Eagle. Take the TO-263 layout from another component and use it to create this component in your library. Add the copper pour on your PCB layout, not the component.

Comment: Is the copper pour only for the two pins of the resistor, or also for heat sink, as displayed in the datasheet *recommended pad layout* section? I've never made my own components yet since it seems like very much work.

Comment: Most of the heat will be dissipated via the heat sink. The traces on the leads should be large enough to handle the current being passed through the device.